# Can someone explain this solution concerning the span of an image?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Why can we pick "any of the two vectors" in R^2 to span the image? Aren't all of them linearly independent, and therefore all of them have to span the image?

Comment: It's important to distinguish "pairwise linearly independence" from linear independence of a set of vectors.  Any pair of those vectors are linearly independent from each other, but if you pick a group of 3 of them, that group is linearly DEpendent.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not all linearly independent.  $\mathbb R^2$ has dimension $2$, which means it has a basis consisting of two vectors, and so (by a theorem you should learn) no set of more than two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ can be linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Not any $2$ vectors in $R^2$ span the image. It is true for $2$ non-parallel vectors, and the reason being that the determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix so formed is non-zero.